# Does checking constant TRUE or FALSE take much operational time?

Tags: c, performance, conditional-statements

Consider a searching algorithm as an example, let it be a sequential searching algorithm. They say the less the amount of conditions a programme checks, the faster the algorithm is. A condition here is considered to be a comparison between some values (like checking equality of values). That is, if there is a comparison in a programme, it does affect the programme performance. And the greater the amount of these comparisons is, the more it takes the programme to terminate.

```
while(comparison)
{body;}
```

But I wonder how would a programme behave if there were no comparison as a condition and some literal expression instead, like:

```
while(TRUE)
{body;}
```

The question is: how different are a literal and a comparison conditions if estimated by performance?

To make this question clearer, consider these pieces of code:

```
while(condition)
{body;}

while(TRUE)
{        
    if (condition) break;
    body;
}
```

And maybe the third one as well which is quite close to the second one:

```
char done = 0;
while (!done)
{        
    if (condition) done++;
    else body;
}
```

Which of these if the fastest one? Are the second and the third ones processed slowlier than the first one?

Comment: Since these two pieces of code are not equivalent at all, I’m not sure this is a meaningful comparison. Yes, the second piece of code will be faster. It also doesn’t work.

Comment: You're really comparing `while (condition) { body; }` to `while (1) { if (!condition) break; body; }`, right?

Comment: @pmg yes that is more reasonable, I'll edit the post

Comment: The third one is different from the other two, it needed to be `while (!done) { if (condition) { done++;} else { body; }}`

Comment: @mevets right, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say a priori anything about the speed.  The compiler of C translates the code in many intermediary languages and during each transformation it changes something in code representation.  Nowadays compilers can make lots of changes to the code.  The only way to understand the performance of the final code is to check the output assembly.  Normally any compiler translates nowadays `while(TRUE) {...}` in a `LOOP: ... goto LOOP` as time as it can prove that `TRUE` is non-zero.

Your question makes sense in the context of minimal compilation or a simple interpretation of the code, when it is faster to use internal functions than using sentinels to represent boolean values.

Comment: There is an update clarifying the question, please check that out

Comment: @Kaiyaha  it is impossible to say, as the translator you use will try to prove things about the code in order to see what changes it can do to the code.   In your code, the translator can translate the ``while (!done) ... `` loop into infinite loop `while (TRUE) { body } ` if it can prove that `(condition)` is all the time false.  The same is true for the 1st case.  See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220997716_Constant_Propagation_with_Conditional_Branches.

Comment: So your answer is that from the compiler point of view now it is impossible to say if the second and the third pieces of code are slower that the first one, right?

Comment: @Kaiyaha  The compiler implements algorithms from the class "Flow Analysis" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_analysis.  So yes, depending on what algorithms the compiler implemented and depending on how the given static analysis prove things about your code, the translated code can differ a lot from the initial code.

Comment: @Kaiyaha In your given example, the algorithm called "constant propagation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding can simplify both of your examples into a simple goto-loop.

Comment: Ok, I should provide a particular example I reckon. https://repl.it/@Kaiyaha/Example#main.c This is a program with a loop. Here I could use `while(condition)` instead of `while(!done)`, which one is better for this situation? This is a sentinel search algorithm of multiple values which terminates anyway and never keeps looping infinitely.

Comment: @Kaiyaha  I repeat, the only one way to see which one is better is to consult the assembly output.   The assembly output depends on what flow-analysis algorithms your compiler runs at static (compilation) time.  It is impossible to say which one is faster otherwise.  You should focus more on the algorithm and data structures you use than on each low-level transformation of your C code.  Unless you run your code on a slow embedded device, you won't see a real difference of speed anyway.

Comment: And if consider this from the algorithm theory's point of view, not from the compiler's?

Comment: @Kaiyaha  Then you need to ask yourself all the time "Can I do better"?  "Can I find some smarter data structures" that help me improve the O(x) time limit?  For example, using "binary decision diagrams" data structure you can solve problems in O(n) instead of O(n^2) for many classical problems...   The same, using the algorithm of Karatsuba is better than using the FFT, for integers up to 50K digitis...  So changing the algorithm will make your code faster...

Answer (score 1):

In this simple example the [assembly output](https://godbolt.org/z/Y3r8aa) is exacly the same:

```c
void f1()
{
    int value = 1;
    while(value) {
        scanf("%d", &value);
    }
}

void f2()
{
    int value = 1;
    while(1) {
        if(value == 0)
            break;
        scanf("%d", &value);
    }
}
```

So they have the same performance.

Whenever in doubt, use compiler explorer to compare the assembly code. Or use a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if the compiler can determine the condition at compile-time, it generates a "branch always" instruction, which in itself is ever so slightly faster than a "branch if set"/"branch if equal" etc.

But more importantly, "branch always" means that the branch prediction feature of the CPU need not speculate about which instructions it will execute next. It can just load upcoming code from program memory into pre-fetch instruction cache, which is fast.

Whereas a "branch if set" would mean that the branch prediction would speculate and take a chance at which code that will get executed, and if it guessed wrong, the code will have to loaded from program memory instead of cache, which is much slower.